# PHP - CURL error when trying to connect with proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am trying to connect a website with CURL using a proxy in PHP. But I get "Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT" error.

This is the code that I use to connect:

```
<?PHP

$ch = curl_init("https://ipinfo.io/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, "HTTP");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "207.154.231.213:8080");

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
    echo curl_error($ch);

echo $output;

?>
```

I don't know what the problem is. The proxy should work perfectly because I check it.

Answer (score 0):

use nex code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ipinfo.io/json");
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo json_decode($result, true);
```

I recommend http://docs.guzzlephp.org/ library for apis for better practices

Comment: I want to connect with a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) you should either remove your `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` setting (to use the default `CURLPROXY_HTTP`), or you need to change your invalid setting

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, "HTTP");
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, "CURLPROXY_HTTP");
```

*Note that the type `HTTP` does not exist.*